# how to create oracle DB using DBCA with specific size eg (20GB)

Tags: oracle11g

I am a newbie in Oracle,i want to create a DB with large size say 20GB.
This db is suppose to be a bakup db where in i am planning to dump old data from other databases,please let me know if this can be achieved with DBCA or i need to use some command once DB is created.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't create "a DB" with a specific size. You create a _tablespace_ with a specific size.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `DATABASE` using default settings as provided using `DBCA`. Make sure you specify a proper `AUTOEXTEND` value for the `DATAFILE`.

The `AUTOEXTEND` tells Oracle to automatically allocate and expand the space used to a specified limit. When the `UNLIMITED` modifier is used, Oracle can use all available space on the device. You could also specify `MAXSIZE` option in conjunction with AUTOEXTEND.

Comment: I have below values of the dbf also i have extended the user tablespace but it is more than the max size,will it allow to store data more that 5GB or it i wll freeze at 3GB (Max size)

Comment: ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\DBTEST\USERS01.DBF'  RESIZE 5000M;

Table space Filename            Size MB  Max Size MB  Autoextendable
USERS  E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\DBTEST\USERS01.DBF  5000  32767.984375 YES
SYSAUX  E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\DBTEST\SYSAUX01.DBF 230   32767.984375 YES
UNDOTBS1 E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\DBTEST\UNDOTBS01.DBF 25   32767.984375 YES
SYSTEM  E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\DBTEST\SYSTEM01.DBF 470   32767.984375 YES

Comment: 3Gb? Are you creating an oracle database on a smartphone or something?

Comment: not on smartphone this a test db since i am testing if my db will autoextend so taken 3GB